# PERMISSION DENIAL: opening provider that is not exported from uid 10083

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, permission-denied

I'm using an adapter for listview where I want to access String from database -> converting it to URI, and put it in an input stream -> decode the input stream with Bitmap factory -> set the new bitmap as image.

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class CardViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Note> notes;

    TextView cardTitleText;
    TextView cardDescriptionText;
    TextView cardDateText;
    ImageView cardImage;

    public CardViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return notes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return notes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);

        cardTitleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextCardView);
        cardDescriptionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextCardView);
        cardDateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTextCardView);
        cardImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);

        Note note = notes.get(position);

        cardTitleText.setText(note.getTitle());
        cardDescriptionText.setText(note.getDescription());
        cardDateText.setText(note.getDate());

        if(note.getImagePath() != null) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(note.getImagePath()));
                databaseImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                cardImage.setImageBitmap(databaseImage);
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) { exception.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the part which I'm talking about and is returning an error

```
  if(note.getImagePath() != null) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(note.getImagePath()));
                databaseImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                cardImage.setImageBitmap(databaseImage);
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException exception) { exception.printStackTrace(); }
        }
```

Here is the error:

```
10-16 20:21:18.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 20:21:18.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11501): Process:     com.meetz.personaljourney, PID: 11501
10-16 20:21:18.566: E/AndroidRuntime(11501): java.lang.SecurityException:   Permission Denial: opening provider    com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider from  ProcessRecord{19ad093 11501:com.meetz.personaljourney/u0a102} (pid=11501,  uid=10102) that is not exported from uid 10083
```

I read every thread on this error on stackoverflow but none of them I tried works. I'm not using any custom provider, so I don't have a provider in my android_manifest.xml. Also, I think that "getContentResolver()" is what returns an error but I don't know why.

------------------------ EDIT ------------------------

Here is the code for getting the image and storing it in the database:

1. I'm using a clicklistener for an image (placeholder) to go to the gallery and get the image. *AddNote is just a class where I placed my methods to clean up my code.

   ```
      addNote.getPopupImage().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()           {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
           String path =     Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
           photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
           startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,   AddNote.IMAGE_GALLERY);
       }
   });
   ```
2. I'm looking for a result and if I get one I use a similar method for retrieving a photo. *addNote.setPopupImage(selectedImage) changes the placeholder with the selected image.

   ```
   @Override     
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if (requestCode == AddNote.IMAGE_GALLERY) {
       Uri photoLocation = data.getData();
       addNote.setPhotoPath(photoLocation.toString());
       try {
           InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoLocation);
           selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
           addNote.setPopupImage(selectedImage);
           inputStream.close();
       } catch (IOException exception) {
           exception.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. This is a code where I add the title, description, date and the selected image to the List and the database. I simply for store the URI as a string to the database, which I then retrieve and parse as URI (the first section of code I posted on the very beginning (adapter))

   ```
           singleNote = new Note(popupTitle.getText().toString(),
                   popupDescription.getText().toString(),
                   new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()),
                   photoPath != null ?  photoPath : "");

           notes.add(singleNote);
           mainDatabase.addNewNote(singleNote);
   ```

If there is anything that's misunderstood, please ask and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: The Uri you're trying to open, is it a file on the SDCard partition? If it is, it might require the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: Where are you getting your image path from? Can you show that code?

Comment: In particular, if you are saving a `Uri` you got from `ACTION_PICK` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` from some time ago, that will not work, as your rights to use those `Uri` values will lapse.

Comment: I'm already using the premission for both reading and writing to storage.

Comment: I'll update the post with new code for getting and storing the image.

Comment: I got the URI from a picture, converted it to string and saved it to my database. When I reopen my app, I'm trying to get that string, parse it as URI again and then use the same URI as the path to access the same image and display it.


Basically, I'm trying to get the saved path from the database to retrieve the same picture once saved to it, and therefore display the very same picture.